# histogram matplotlib, text out of histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

with python and matplotlib, I can plot a histogram and I can put a text in the histogram area,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


a = np.array([10, 10, 10, 8, 9, 9, 7])

mean = np.mean(a)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.hist(a, alpha=0.2)

ax.set_ylabel(u'Frequency')
ax.set_xlabel(u'Some data')
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.8, -0.1)

ax.text(mean, 0, '$\mu$\n{}'.format(mean))

plt.show()
```

how I can put the text under the axis?

[image: histogram]

Comment: You could use '\n' to skip lines to bring it down. That may work for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative value for `y`:

```
ax.text(mean, -0.3, '$\mu$\n{}'.format(mean))
```